# Use of string reversion in conlangs

Tags: morphology, unnatural-features, list-of-languages

I came across the Esperantido [Universal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_(Esperantido)) where reversion of stems (e.g., *mega* "big" ⁒ *gema* "small", -a is the adjective ending) is used to denote antonymy. Are there other conlangs using this unusual and un-naturalistic device?

Comment: Hmm interesting. Limited reversal, called [metathesis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metathesis_(linguistics)), does occur in many languages and sometimes with a grammatical meaning, but not whole words.

Comment: I thought there was a section in Mark Rosenfelder's *Language Construction Kit* setting forth a scheme in which the forms of a verb are distinguished (in part) by permutation; but can't now find it.

Comment: Ah here it is. Only the vowels move about. http://www.zompist.com/kebreni.htm#Verbs

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Solresol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solresol#Vocabulary) actually reverses the syllable order of a word to denote an opposite meaning, though this occurrence is inconsistent through the creator's published dictionary. For example, *fala* means good, but *lafa* means bad, and *falaredo* means accessible, but *dorelafa* means inaccessible.